# Entropy of product space with dependent components

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, entropy

> > A *(two-sided) topological Markov shift* is a system $(W,S)$ defined by a matrix $A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^k$ with entries in $\left\{0,1\right\}$ as follows. $W$ is the subset of $\left\{1,\ldots,k\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ consisting of sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ with the property that $a_{x_n,x_{n+1}}=1$ for all $n$ and $S$ is simply the transformation that shifts a sequence one unit to the left. Then the topological entropy is $h(W,S)=\log\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the largest positive eigenvalue of $A$. The same holds for one-sided Markov shift (i.e. when considering only the sequences in, for example, $\left\{1,\ldots,k\right\}^{\mathbb{N}}$).

Now to my question. Assume we consider two symmetric one-sided topological Markov shifts, one with the left-shift $S_L$, the other with the right-shift $S_R$. More precisely, let

$W_L\subset\left\{1,\ldots,k\right\}^{\mathbb{Z>0}}$ with some matrix $A_L$ such that $S_L$ acts as the left shift on $W_L$. Assume $h(W_S,S_L)=\ln\lambda$ with $\lambda$ being the largest positive eigenvalue of $A_L$.

Moreover, let $W_R\subset\left\{1,\ldots,k\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}}$ with some matrix $A_R$ such that $S_R$ acts as the right shift on $W_R$ and assume that $h(W_R,S_R)=\ln\lambda$.

Then, in case both systems do not depend on each other, we have
$$
h(W_R\times W_L,S_R\times S_L)=h(W_R,S_R)+h(W_L,S_L)=2\ln\lambda.
$$

Now, suppose we have some function $a(w_R,w_L)\in\left\{-1,0,1\right\}$ with $w_R\in W_R, w_L\in W_L$ and we want to compute or estimate the topological entropy
$$
h(W_R\times W_L,S_R^{1-a(\cdot,\cdot)}\times S_L^{1+a(\cdot,\cdot)}).
$$

(That is, if, for example, $a(w_R,w_L)=1$, we are not shifting $w_R$ at all, but shift $w_L$ twice to the left.)

**Question:**

Since for each choice of $w_R\in W_R$ and $w_L\in W_L$, we have 
$$
(1-a(w_R,w_L)) + (1+a(w_R,w_L))=2,
$$
and we have, in general, that $h(S_R^0)=h(\text{id})=0, h(S_R^2)=2h(S_R)$ and, similarly, $h(S_L^0)=0$ and $h(S_L^2)=2h(S_L)$,
do we have again
$$
h(W_R\times W_L,S_R^{1-a(\cdot,\cdot)}\times S_L^{1+a(\cdot,\cdot)})=2\ln\lambda
$$
or at least get an upper estimate
$$
h(W_R\times W_L,S_R^{1-a(\cdot,\cdot)}\times S_L^{1+a(\cdot,\cdot)})\leq 2\ln\lambda
$$
or lower estimate
$$
h(W_R\times W_L,S_R^{1-a(\cdot,\cdot)}\times S_L^{1+a(\cdot,\cdot)})\geq 2\ln\lambda?
$$

For me that would be not too absurd since for each argument $(w_R,w_L)$ we make two shifts, effectively: If $a(w_R,w_L)=0$, we do a single shift in each component and if $a(w_R,w_L)=-1$ or $a(w_R,w_L)=1$, we do a double shift in one component and no shift in the other.

Comment: It seems to me that the answer is yes, *provided that the function $a$ is continuous*. As usual, you only need to count the number of cylinder sets of some length, and in this case the number won't change if you count around zero. I don't see the relevance for the problem of what you mention about the identity and the second power.

Answer (score 1):

Detailing my answer above:

The answer is yes, provided that the function $a$ is continuous. In fact, the question doesn't even make sense otherwise since the entropy is defined for continuous maps.

As usual, you only need to count the number of cylinder sets of some length, and in this case the number won't change if you count around zero. So indeed the number of cylinders of a given length is the same as when $a$ vanishes. This gives your intended result.

Comment: I do not exactly Unterstand what you mean with the Second Paragraph starting with "As usual...".

Comment: Maybe you can give some Details?

Comment: Sorry but this is no help. Why so rude? I think the Situation is not so simple here that it would not be okay to ask for some Details about what exactly you mean with 'count cylinder sets', 'as usual' etc.

Comment: Since your question is quite nontrivial, you should know the basics and should not be so rude as you are: instead you should show appreciation with whom looses time with you. Also, you should study, a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to be impolite. The point is that I do know what cylinder sets are and how topological entropy is defined. But I do not know what you mean with counting cylinder sets of some length; moreover, we have a product space here and that makes it even more hard to understand what you are using.

Comment: Do I understand it right that you identify both semi-infinite sequences with one bi-infinite sequence and then look for the minimal $(n,2^{-k})$-spanning set whose cardinality should be something like $\lvert\mathcal{B}_{n+2k}\rvert$, the number of blocks of length $n+2k$ appearing in elements of the bi-infinite configurations? Here the metric is $d(x,y)=2^{-k}$ with k maximal sucht that x and y coincide on [-k,k] around position 0.

Comment: Please explain to me why the function a does not change the number of cylinder sets for some length resp. the minimal cardinality of an $(n,2^{-k})$-spanning set.